# When i close my application, cursor returns 0 in SQLiteHelper. SomeOne for helping me?

Tags: android-sqlite

When i ask my database all is ok

```
 /** Affichage des textes -----------------------------------------------------------------*/
    if (textViewPointdepart4.text != "D11111111111111111") {
        val textViewVotrescore = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView_Votrescore)
        val db = SQLiteHelper(this)
        val cursor = db.gettablelieu()
        Log.e("Cursor", cursor.count.toString())
        if (cursor.count == 0) {
            toastMakeText(applicationContext, "Pas de donnée trouvée", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        } else {
            cursor.moveToFirst()
            textViewPointdepart4.text = cursor.getString(1)
            textViewTitre4.text = cursor.getString(2)
            textViewLieu.text = cursor.getString(3)
            buttonIntrigue.text = cursor.getString(4)
            buttonGeo.text = cursor.getString(5)
            buttonIntrigue2.text = cursor.getString(6)
            textViewVotrescore.text = cursor.getString(8)
        }
```

...

' et celui de SQLiteHelper'

```
/** Lecture des données de la tablelieu ------------------------------------------------------*/
public Cursor gettablelieu() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteHelper.this.getReadableDatabase();
    SharedPreferences sp = appContext.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("Test", 0);
    String item = sp.getString("Pointdepart", "");
    String query = "SELECT * FROM tablelieu WHERE Pointdepart ='" +item + "'";
    Log.e("query", query);
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
   return cursor;
}
```

'But when i close my application and i run it again cursor returns 0 and i have no data return

```
public static synchronized SQLiteHelper getInstance(Context context) { 
    if (sInstance == null) { 
        sInstance = new SQLiteHelper(context.getApplicationContext()); 
    } 
    return sInstance; 
} 
public SQLiteHelper(Context applicationcontext ) { 
    super(applicationcontext, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1); 
    this.appContext = applicationcontext; 
}
```

Comment: Please show your `SQLiteHelper` constructor

Comment: public static synchronized SQLiteHelper getInstance(Context context) {
        if (sInstance == null) {
            sInstance = new SQLiteHelper(context.getApplicationContext());
        }
        return sInstance;
    }
    public SQLiteHelper(Context applicationcontext ) {
        super(applicationcontext, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
        this.appContext =  applicationcontext;

    }